# Relationship between a polynomial and its first derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

Consider a polynomial $f(x)$ and its derivative $f'(x)$ that are related according to: $f(x) - f'(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 1$.  What is $f(9)$?

I am not sure how to proceed with it. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It would be nice, if you include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

differentiating and differentiating, we get

$$f (x )-f'(x)=x^3+3x^2+3x+1$$
$$f'(x)-f''(x)=3x^2+6x+3$$
$$f''(x)-f'''(x)=6x+6$$
$$f'''(x)-f''''(x)=6$$
but $$f''''(x)=0$$
since the degree of  $f (x) $ is $\le 3$.

thus
$$f'''(9)=6$$
$$f''(9)=6+6.9+6=66$$
$$f'(9)=66+3.9^2+6.9+3=366$$
$$f (9)=366+9^3+3.9^2+3.9+1=1366$$

Sure.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see that $f(x)$ has degree at most $3$ (can you see why?). So that means, because $f$ is a polynomial, that we can write $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx +d$ for some real numbers $a,b,c,d$. Now work out what $f'(x)$ is and hence what the left hand side of the equation that you have been given is. Can you work out now what $a,b,c$ and $d$ are?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can understand it now. So a=1, b=6, c=15 and d=16. When we substitute a,b,c,d in f(x) for x=9 we got a result of 1351.

Comment: Maybe check the calculation again. I get 1366 but I may have made a mistake. I get the same coefficients ($a,b,c,d$) as you though.

Comment: @DanRust yes it is $1366$. no doubt.